# Measurement paradox

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis, noise, instrument

When building electronics to measure usually it is asked what the bandwidth of the signal is and what is the frequency range usually done to limit noise bandwidth and thus have more SNR. To me it seems like measurements are preconditioned, I know what I want to measure and I limit my equipment to that expectation. Why there is no paradox in the sense that I prepared the measurement to measure what I expected and then I measured what I expected?

Comment: Is there a paradox when you buy a 12" ruler and then measure something to be 6.5"?

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: This is a fine question, but since it has been closed, I'll summarize an answer in a comment. This is part of Bohr's complementarity principle: the measurement apparatus measures what is in its nature to measure. What bothers some people is that at the quantum level, that precludes measurement of some complementary property of the system. It's like your bandwidth restriction, which broadens the impulse response, preventing you measuring the time of an event precisely. The only special thing in the quantum world is that you can't split the signal to measure the complementary properties.